# Building line integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to following exercise (with solutions):
[image: Problem]
But I don't understand how they build the integrals from $\int_{\partial D} P dx + Q dy$, as it should be $F(r(t))$, with $F=P$ and $r(t)$ according to the parameterization. How do they get $(1-t^2,t^2)$?

Comment: $F$ is not $P$, $F$ is $(P,Q)$. They are integrating $F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is to integrate the field $F=(P,Q)$ on the curve $r(t)$. So you need to compute $$\int F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)dt.$$ Note that you have two curves so you have to sum both integrals.